# NodeJS Cookie wrong expiration date

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, cookies

Here is the snippet I use to send the Set-Cookie back to the client

```
let cookieAttributes = {
  httpOnly: true,
  secure: true,
};

if (rememberme)
  cookieAttributes.expires = new Date(Date.now() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 14)
                    
res.cookie("token", token, cookieAttributes);
                    
res.status(200).send();

console.log(res);
```

Even tough I set cookieAttributes to expire in 60 * 60 * 24 * 14 (14 days), looking at the response in the console and the cookie in the browser I see that the cookie is due to expire in about 10 minutes:

```
'set-cookie': [ 'Set-Cookie', 'token=*redacted*; Path=/; Expires=Mon, 10 Aug 2020 17:16:18 GMT; HttpOnly; Secure' ]
```

Yes, *rememberme* is set to true, I have the same problem if I use maxAge instead of expires

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression 60 * 60 * 24 * 14 is in seconds, you should convert it to milliseconds.
Just multiple it by 1000.

```
cookieAttributes.expires = new Date(Date.now() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 14 * 1000)
```